# langmap in vim seems to be recursive

Tags: vim, binding

I have `gcc` shortcut mapped in normal mode (standard tComment shortcut). If I use

```
set langmap=ij;gc
```

typing `ijj` works as expected. But if I use

`set langmap=ijg;gcu`

when trying the same shortcut I get: `Invalid register name: '$'`. What's the difference between those mappings?

Comment: It works normally, here. See if you have a mapping somewhere that could erroneously call `"$`.

Comment: Do I understand right that first nnoremap is being applied and then langmap applies on top of that? Because that's what I see happening for me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching I've found this thread: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.editors.vim.devel/36307

It looks like indeed langmap applies to the right side of mappings, so using langmap will interfere with any existing user-created bindings. I am not quite sure what the purpose of that because that makes this feature pretty much useless.